# Is setting Android MediaPlayer player to null when releasing necessary?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-memory

Looking at the example on how to release an Android MediaPlayer instance on the official document, it is says that we should **nullify** the object after releasing it:

> Here's how you should release and then nullify your MediaPlayer:

```
mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null; // <-- instruction I am asking about.
```

Is this actually necessary? If so, why?

*Source:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#releaseplayer*

Comment: **Every** object should be `nullified`, after usage. In **every** language, and on **every** OS.

Comment: I know it's good for GC, but the problem is Android Studio warns me saying "The value null assigned to 'audioRecord' is never used". If this way of releasing resources is recommended, would it be necessary for syntax checkers to be aware of it instead of popping up a waring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `null` is to mark the GC that it can 'collect' that object.